# How to show an image from an url in android

Tags: android, imageview

I have looked around the internet but haven't been able to find a **working** example on how to show an image from an url.

The below code is crashing and I can't find out why.. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

TesteImages.java:

```
package pac.image3;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class TestImages extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.test_image);

        String imageUrl = "http://www.small-world.net/_borders/small_world_logo.gif";
        try {
          ImageView i = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.test_image);
          Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(imageUrl).getContent());
          i.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
          setContentView(image);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

res/layout/main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />

    <ImageView 
   android:id="@+id/test_image"
   android:src="@drawable/icon"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use the following method to draw image from url:

```
Drawable drawable_from_url(String url, String src_name) throws 
   java.net.MalformedURLException, java.io.IOException 
{
   return Drawable.createFromStream(((java.io.InputStream)
      new java.net.URL(url).awagetContent()), src_name);
}
```

Just pass the string url to the method(and for src_name any string ) and it will return you a drawable object, then use **setBckgroundDrawable()** method of the imageview to set the background of the image.

Comment: thanks for your reply. wouldn't you mind  to provide how would this function integrate with the the source code in the question? It would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You just need to call this method and pass the string url to this method. It will return you a drawable object . Now cant you set the background of your imageView with this drawable using **setBackgroundDrawable() or setImageDrawable()**. I think this is what you want....

Comment: What is awagetContent() in your answer?? Its not getting recognized in eclipse it instead gives an option to replace it with getContent() and then image wont load it always shows a blank screen

Comment: Important : this answer worked for me when been called inside the method "doInBackground" of an AsyncTask class, because Android demands do URL access in separate thread.

Answer (score 2):

Do not try **Bitmap** in the code. Just use simple `Drawable` image and implement its method like below. you will display image 100 percent

```
Drawable drw =LoadImageFromWebOperations(imageUrl);
image.setImageDrawable(drw);

return  image;

private Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String strPhotoUrl) 
    {
        try
        {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(strPhotoUrl).getContent();
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
        return d;
        }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exc="+e);
        return null;
        }
```

Comment: Important : this answer worked for me when been called inside the method "doInBackground" of an AsyncTask class, because Android demands do URL access in separate thread.