# Android how to make a http request to get image link for ImageView

Tags: android, http, request, imageview

how to make a http request to get image link:
http://vec03.maps.yandex.ru/tiles?l=map&v=2.20.0&x=19783&y=10320&z=15
to be able to add to ImageView

Please help, I'm not good in web development.

Comment: Open URL connection and get image as Bitmap now set Bitmap as ImageView. Look at this tutorial, http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238524/how-to-show-an-image-from-an-url-in-android

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html

Answer (score 9):

```
String imageUrl= "http://vec03.maps.yandex.ru/tiles?l=map&v=2.20.0&x=19783&y=10320&z=15";
URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
HttpURLConnection connection  = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);  

imageView.setImageBitmap(img );
```

Google it before you ask your problem in SO, avoid duplicate Questions

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setImage()
    {
     ImageView icon=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon);


                                   Drawable image = ImageOperations(getapplicationContext(), "yuour url",
                                     "image.jpg");


                                   icon.setImageDrawable(image);
    }
private Drawable ImageOperations(Context ctx, String url,
               String saveFilename) {
              try {
               InputStream is = (InputStream) this.fetch(url);
               Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
               return d;
              } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
               return null;
              } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
               return null;
              }
    }
              public Object fetch(String address) throws MalformedURLException,
               IOException {
              URL url = new URL(address);
              Object content = url.getContent();
              return content;
             }
```