# how to display an image from the web in android

Tags: java, android

How do you load an image from a URL and then display it in the view in android and java?

I've tried using all sorts of different code examples AsyncTasks to synchronous HTTP requests. 
This is the last thing I tried:

```
public Object fetch() throws MalformedURLException,IOException {
        URL url = new URL("https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png");
        Object content = url.getContent();
        return content;
    }
```

Comment: Have you done any research at Google before asking something like this??

Comment: Picasso makes this incredibly easy - https://github.com/square/picasso

Comment: @Pavlos Yes, in fact many long hours worth. That's why I finally decided to ask. I've tried many other solutions presented by similar questions.

Comment: I am not quite sure! Anyway you can use Picasso or Glide or Ion or something else similar!

Comment: After a bit of work, (I needed to hook it into AsyncTask) Picasso worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) is a good and easy to use library for loading images from the Internet. You can do this job as easy as writing this single line of code

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Drawable drawable_from_url(String url, String src_name) throws 
   java.net.MalformedURLException, java.io.IOException 
{
   return Drawable.createFromStream(((java.io.InputStream)
      new java.net.URL(url).awagetContent()), src_name);
}
```

source: [How to show an image from an url in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238524/how-to-show-an-image-from-an-url-in-android)

Comment: I had the same problem as the person who asked that question. "awagetContent()" isn't a function, and changing it to getContent() generates an error.